# Why I can't able to find my app is listed on android wear Apps Launcher?

Tags: android, wear-os

As I am exploring android wear stuff.

I had tried to fire some notification from phone app to android wear as a demo and it works fine.

But I can't able to find my app is listed on android wear Apps Launcher/Apps List?

It's just a sample "Hello World" created from Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5 wizard. No modification except added notification related code in mobile module.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a hello world application on Android wear? I am confused about what you are asking.

Comment: can't able to find my app is listed on android wear apps list. can you help me?

Comment: I still don't understand, on the app store?

Comment: not app store but in Android Wear device App Launcher.

Comment: If you have an `activity` element in your manifest with `action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"` and `category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`, it should show up in the launcher on-device (this is as true on Wear as on any other Android device). Please add the relevant code from your manifest to your question.

Comment: @String Yes both module's manifest has launcher activity.

will it be sync automatically when I install app in phone then wear will get  that app even if in debug mode ?

Comment: Not in debug mode, no. Try installing the wearable apk on the wearable device manually, and tell us if that works.

Comment: Are you saying that your app isn't even getting installed on the Wear device? If so, that would have been useful information to include in your original question - and that's the obvious reason why it's not listed in the Launcher.

Comment: Yes, got installed wear app on release apk. Thanks (y)